# image resizing in node.js

Tags: image-processing, canvas, node.js

I am trying to resize image in node.js by this program .

https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/blob/master/examples/resize.js

```
var Canvas = require('canvas')
  , Image = Canvas.Image
  , fs = require('fs');

var img = new Image
  , start = new Date;
img.src = __dirname + 'flowers.jpg';

console.log('Resized and saved in %dms');
img.onload = function(){
  console.log('Resized and saved in buffer');
  try{
  var width = img.width / 2
    , height = img.height / 2
    , canvas = new Canvas(width, height)
    , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  canvas.toBuffer(function(err, buf){
    console.log('Resized and saved in buffer');
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/resize.jpg', buf, function(){
      console.log('Resized and saved in %dms', new Date - start);
    });
  });
  }catch(e){
    console.log(sys.inspect(e));
  }
};

img.onerror = function(err){
  throw err;
};
```

the program is not going in the onload function why ?
Edit :
give this error while trying  img.src after attaching the onload and onerror events?

```
`Resized and saved in NaNms

/home/reach121/rahul/knox/index.js:33
 throw err;
 ^
Error: error while reading from input stream
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/reach121/rahul/knox/index.js:35:9)
   at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
   at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
   at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
   at Array.0 (module.js:423:10)
   at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:170:26)
```

Using Image Magic giving me this error :

```
reach121@youngib:~/rahul/knox$ sudo node index.js

node.js:178
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Command failed: execvp(): No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/imagemagick/0.1.2/package/imagemagick.js:64:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:172:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Array.<anonymous> (net.js:826:12)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:170:26)
```

Code :

```
var im = require('imagemagick');

im.resize({
  srcPath: __dirname + '/flowers.jpg',
  dstPath: __dirname + '/flowers-small.jpg',
  width:   '50%'
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('resized')
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you already tried setting `img.src` after attaching the `onload` and `onerror` events? Just noticed this as a difference between the original example and yours.

Another question: is the `onerror` event triggered? If so, the thrown exception could be helpful.

**Update**

If you just want to resize images and don't need to use any canvas-specific operations, simply use [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/) and [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick). I just did a small test and it worked out of the box:

```
var im = require('imagemagick');

im.resize({
  srcPath: __dirname + '/koala.jpg',
  dstPath: __dirname + '/koala-small.jpg',
  width:   '50%'
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('resized')
});
```

Comment: `Resized and saved in NaNms

/home/reach121/rahul/knox/index.js:33
 throw err;
 ^
Error: error while reading from input stream
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/reach121/rahul/knox/index.js:35:9)
   at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
   at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
   at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
   at Array.0 (module.js:423:10)
   at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:170:26)

Comment: @Rahul you need to install imagemagick. node-imagemagick simply executes the installed binary https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick/blob/master/imagemagick.js

Comment: please consider reading the documentation on the module before posting further errors.

Comment: I installed the imagemagick already .. Please check the error

Comment: where did you install imagemagick? inside your PATH env or somewhere else (for example in your home directory)?

Comment: i'm talking about imagemagick, not node-imagemagick. npm reads "Node Package Manager", you have to install ImageMagick (which has nothing to do with node). Read the installation documentation on http://www.imagemagick.org/.

Answer (score 2):

For the node_imagemagick module to work you need to install the imagemagick CLI interfaces,

On a mac it can be as easy as:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

But this really depends on your specific system.

Answer (score 0):

`__dirname` does not have a trailing slash.

Change it to this:

```
img.src = __dirname + '/flowers.jpg';
```

And attach event handlers before setting img.src like @schaermu said.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, your console.log statement uses a %d but there's no variable after the quoted string. (I'm not sure this solves your other errors.)